# How to have AngularJS 1.6 call a function a single time when the user updates an input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written some AngularJS code that allows the user to enter some numbers into some inputs in a browser and then see lines drawn on an `svg` element in response.

The `svg` element has a number of child `line` elements.  Each one has attributes x1, x2, y1, y2, and style.  Each one of these attributes has a computed value.  Each computed value is a property of an object that is returned from a Javascript function.  That means that the Javascript function is called *five times*: once for each attribute of each line.

In order to unclutter my display code and improve performance, I wrote a Javascript function that returns an array of objects with each objects containing the values for the attributes x1, x2, y1, y2, and style of a single line element.  I thought it was a simple and reasonable solution.

My code now looks like this:

```
<line ng-repeat="line in getLines()" x1="{{line.x1}}" x2="{{line.x2}}
      y1="{{line.y1}}" y2="{{line.y2}}" ng-style="line.style" />
```

When I run this code, I get an AngularJS infdig error, indicating that the model would be computed an infinite number of times.  I checked the documentation for this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

It says: *One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called.... The solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not changed.*

That last part doesn't help at all because the contents of that array do, indeed, change with every number entered into the form.

I feel like I'm doing something to make this harder than it should be.

What I want is that when the user modifies one or more numbers in the input fields, the function `getLines` should be called a single time and the results should be used to populate the attributes of various `line` elements so that the user can see lines in the browser.

How do I make sure that `getLines` is called a single time when the inptu fields are updated?

Comment: x2 missing closing double quotes

Comment: Can you add code of `getLines()` as well.  I think in this implementation `getLines()` will be called in every dirty check and it'll keep on triggering new cycles. Please provide us enough code to understand your logic. May be it could be done in some other way as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is:

Inputs:

```
<input id="x1" type="text" ng-change="changeHandler(elem)"/>
.
.
<input id="y2" type="text" ng-change="changeHandler(elem)"/>
```

Handlers:

```
function changeHandler(elem) {

    //Get value from event
    if (elem.id = 'x1')

        if (line.x1 != elem.value) {
            //Call function to update svg
            applyChange(line)
        }
    //.
    //.
    //.
    else if (elem.id = 'y2')

        if (line.y2 != elem.value) {
            applyChange(line)
        }


}
```

Comment: Thank you.  After reading your answer, I tried something slightly different.  I created getter/setters on the values that `getLines` depends on.  That way, it is unnecessary to use `ng-change` and if the app is modified so that these values are modified elsewhere, the changes will be reflected in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what getLines is doing. But I think you should try to store the lines values in an object, and use that object for the ng-repeat instead of the function. And use ngChange to trigger an event when an field is modified.

Comment: Berci is correct but should expand a bit upon what he is describing. Instead of ng-repeat="line in getLines()" you should have ng-repeat="line in lines" where lines is an array on your $scope and the input fields should trigger updateLines() on change .